# How to display only first product among products with same pkid and color using MySQL query

Tags: mysql

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, 
b.subcattitle, 
c.largephotofilename,  
d.title AS cattitle, 
f.title AS colortitle, 
n.title AS sizetitle 
FROM t_store a 
LEFT JOIN t_store_cat d ON a.catpkid=d.catpkid AND d.visible='YES' 
LEFT JOIN t_store_subcat b ON a.subcatpkid=b.subcatpkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_photo c ON a.pkid=c.masterpkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_color e ON a.pkid=e.itempkid 
LEFT JOIN t_store_color f ON e.masterpkid=f.pkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_size m ON a.pkid=m.itempkid 
LEFT JOIN t_store_size n ON m.masterpkid=n.pkid 
WHERE a.visible='YES' AND b.visible='YES' AND c.visible='YES' 
AND a.catpkid = 5 
ORDER BY a.createdatetime DESC
```

**SQL Query Result**

```
pkid    catpkid subcatpkid  title       description     createdatetime          visible     listprice   ourprice    memberprice     subcattitle largephotofilename  cattitle    colortitle  sizetitle   
132     5       118         Title01     Desc01          2020-07-15 14:44:51     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat01    image001.jpeg       cat001      Gray        L
132     5       118         Title01     Desc01          2020-07-15 14:44:51     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat01    image001.jpeg       cat001      Gray        XL
132     5       118         Title01     Desc01          2020-07-15 14:44:51     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat01    image001.jpeg       cat001      Gray        XXL
135     5       118         Title02     Desc02          2020-07-15 16:26:52     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat01    image002.jpeg       cat001      Pink        L
135     5       118         Title02     Desc02          2020-07-15 16:26:52     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat01    image002.jpeg       cat001      Pink        XL
135     5       118         Title02     Desc02          2020-07-15 16:26:52     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat01    image002.jpeg       cat001      Pink        XXL
135     5       118         Title02     Desc02          2020-07-15 16:26:52     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat01    image002.jpeg       cat001      Pink        XXXL
```

I want to make so only first product with same pkid and color should display in product listing. Currently they are displaying as 3 different products because they have same pkid and color but different sizes.

I tried to use `DISTINCT` with `colortitle` field but it is not working properly. So what changes do I need to make in query to display only first product instead of 3 products.

**UPDATED QUERY**

```
SELECT a.pkid, 
b.subcattitle, 
c.largephotofilename,  
d.title AS cattitle, 
f.title AS colortitle, 
group_concat(n.title ) AS sizetitle 
FROM t_store a 
LEFT JOIN t_store_cat d ON a.catpkid=d.catpkid AND d.visible='YES' 
LEFT JOIN t_store_subcat b ON a.subcatpkid=b.subcatpkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_photo c ON a.pkid=c.masterpkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_color e ON a.pkid=e.itempkid 
LEFT JOIN t_store_color f ON e.masterpkid=f.pkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_size m ON a.pkid=m.itempkid 
LEFT JOIN t_store_size n ON m.masterpkid=n.pkid 
WHERE a.visible='YES' AND b.visible='YES' AND c.visible='YES' 
AND a.catpkid = 5 
GROUP BY a.pkid
ORDER BY a.createdatetime DESC
```

**UPDATED MYSQL QUERY RESULT**

```
pkid    catpkid subcatpkid  title       description     createdatetime          visible     listprice   ourprice    memberprice     subcattitle largephotofilename  cattitle    colortitle  sizetitle   
132     5       118         Title01     Desc01          2020-07-15 14:44:51     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat01    image001.jpeg       cat001      Gray        L,L,L,L,XL,XL,XL,XL,XXL,XXL,XXL,XXL
```

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x=...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different size so DISTINCT can't return a single row for color and pkid
if the size is not important you could try using an aggregation function eg as  group_concat that return all the size in a single row

```
SELECT  a.pkid, 
b.subcattitle, 
c.largephotofilename,  
d.title AS cattitle, 
f.title AS colortitle, 
group_concat(n.title ) AS sizetitle 
FROM t_store a 
LEFT JOIN t_store_cat d ON a.catpkid=d.catpkid AND d.visible='YES' 
LEFT JOIN t_store_subcat b ON a.subcatpkid=b.subcatpkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_photo c ON a.pkid=c.masterpkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_color e ON a.pkid=e.itempkid 
LEFT JOIN t_store_color f ON e.masterpkid=f.pkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_size m ON a.pkid=m.itempkid 
LEFT JOIN t_store_size n ON m.masterpkid=n.pkid 
WHERE a.visible='YES' AND b.visible='YES' AND c.visible='YES' 
AND a.catpkid = 5 
GROUP BY a.pkid, b.subcattitle, c.largephotofilename,  d.title , f.title 
ORDER BY a.createdatetime DESC
```

or a min() or max()

```
SELECT a.pkid, 
b.subcattitle, 
c.largephotofilename,  
d.title AS cattitle, 
f.title AS colortitle, 
min(n.title ) AS sizetitle 
FROM t_store a 
LEFT JOIN t_store_cat d ON a.catpkid=d.catpkid AND d.visible='YES' 
LEFT JOIN t_store_subcat b ON a.subcatpkid=b.subcatpkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_photo c ON a.pkid=c.masterpkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_color e ON a.pkid=e.itempkid 
LEFT JOIN t_store_color f ON e.masterpkid=f.pkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_size m ON a.pkid=m.itempkid 
LEFT JOIN t_store_size n ON m.masterpkid=n.pkid 
WHERE a.visible='YES' AND b.visible='YES' AND c.visible='YES' 
AND a.catpkid = 5 
GROUP BY a.pkid, b.subcattitle, c.largephotofilename,  d.title , f.title 
ORDER BY a.createdatetime DESC
```

anyway if you use group by you can't use the  select all operator `*`,  you must explicitally declare in select clause the column name you need  not involved by aggreagtion and repated  these column in group by clause
in my sample i have used onl a.pkid

Comment: Ty for you reply. So I must declare all required fields instead of `a.*` and then mention all those columns in `GROUP BY` statement. Please let me know.

Comment: Yes  ..all columns in select   not used  in aggregation function must be explicitally declared ( or you could build a more complex query using a join between table a and the subquery for all the others left joined  tables ..but seems too complext to me in this case)  .

Comment: I am still using `SELECT DISTINCT a.*,` and getting only 1 product with same pkid and color. So it is giving result as I wanted. But not sure why it is still working even I am using `a.*` and `GROUP BY` together in query. Please explain

Comment: I'm sorry answer  updated ..  removing the unuseful distinct  ..anyway  ..  you comment is not clear to  me ..  you should provide the full code and explain berret your comment

Comment: I have added my final query as per your response. You can see that I am using `a.*` and `GROUP By` in query and still it is working. While you were saying that I must not use `*.a` in query if I am using `GROUP BY`. So I was just curious that why it is giving proper result as I wanted. Please let me know my question is clear to you now.

Comment: THis mean that you are using a mysql version < 5.7  ..  so this work but the value showed  in the single row are random  .. for version starting from 5.t this produce an error  ..in your case work but is not the right way for use group by and obtain single row.. hope this comment is clear  ..

Comment: Ty for your clarification, I will change my query according to your suggestion.

Comment: Please look at `UPDATED MYSQL QUERY RESULT` I added to my original question. You will see `L,L,L,L,XL,XL,XL,XL,XXL,XXL,XXL,XXL` as a value of sizetitle. So is it possible that sizetitle should display only first value like `L`. Please let me know. Otherwise your query is working fine and now displaying only 1 result for same pkid and color.

Comment: if you instead of group_concat(n,title)  use min(n.title)  ..  you get only one value and not the full string .. (as suggested  in th second query in my answer)

Comment: Hi, there is small issue... when size is same or nothing and there are 2 colors then above query displays same record 2 times... if there are 3 colors then displays same record 3 times... How to fix it in above query. Please reply.

Comment: @RKAhir  the better way is post a new question add  a proper (specific) data sample  ..  the code you are  using .. you actual result and your expected  result .. so all the SO commnunity could be involved for help you ... when you have done  this comment me the related  link ..

Comment: Hi, here is the new question as you suggested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63127130/how-to-get-rid-off-duplicate-records-with-same-color-or-size-using-mysql-query

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works, its good if you provide details of table structure and some sample data.
This approach is using `row_number()` which gives you the number for each rows and we are using `over(partition by pkid)` which would start the series of sequence number unless there is a change in pkid, if there is a change it again starts with 1 till it finds another change. So my idea is to filter out the 1st one from them and then join them out.
So your table `t_store a` has this functions in an inline view.

```
(select *,row_number() over(partition by pkid) as rn from t_store) a
```

Suggested change :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, 
b.subcattitle, 
c.largephotofilename,  
d.title AS cattitle, 
f.title AS colortitle, 
n.title AS sizetitle 
FROM (select *,row_number() over(partition by pkid) as rn from t_store) a 
LEFT JOIN t_store_cat d ON a.catpkid=d.catpkid AND d.visible='YES'  and a.rn=1
LEFT JOIN t_store_subcat b ON a.subcatpkid=b.subcatpkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_photo c ON a.pkid=c.masterpkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_color e ON a.pkid=e.itempkid 
LEFT JOIN t_store_color f ON e.masterpkid=f.pkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_size m ON a.pkid=m.itempkid 
LEFT JOIN t_store_size n ON m.masterpkid=n.pkid 
WHERE a.visible='YES' AND b.visible='YES' AND c.visible='YES' and a.rn=1
AND a.catpkid = 5 
ORDER BY a.createdatetime DESC
```

Comment: Ty for your reply and I will try it now but what is `a.rn=1` in your query. Please explain so I can understand.

Comment: So, I should simply put hardcode `a.rn=1` like you mentioned in your answer. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, i suggest it, you are simply taking the first row from the group of pkid..also please check if you are getting expected result.

Comment: I am getting this error - Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by pkid) AS rn FROM t_store) a LEFT JOIN t_store_cat d ON a.catpkid=d' at line 1

Comment: i have made several changes, can you copy again the latest one and try ?

Comment: I could't figure similar query with exactly same syntax is working, can you provide the create table and sample data and set up a dbfiddle ? which version of mysql are you using ?

Comment: Ty for your help but other query worked for me properly.