# How to get rid off duplicate records with same color or size using MySQL query

Tags: mysql

**Initial SQL Query Result**

```
pkid    catpkid subcatpkid  title       description     createdatetime          visible     listprice   ourprice    memberprice     subcattitle largephotofilename  cattitle    colortitle  sizetitle   
132     5       118         Title01     Desc01          2020-07-15 14:44:51     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat01    image001.jpeg       cat001      Gray        L
132     5       118         Title01     Desc01          2020-07-15 14:44:51     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat01    image001.jpeg       cat001      Gray        XL
132     5       118         Title01     Desc01          2020-07-15 14:44:51     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat01    image001.jpeg       cat001      Gray        XXL
135     5       118         Title02     Desc02          2020-07-15 16:26:52     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat01    image002.jpeg       cat001      Pink        L
135     5       118         Title02     Desc02          2020-07-15 16:26:52     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat01    image002.jpeg       cat001      Pink        XL
135     5       118         Title02     Desc02          2020-07-15 16:26:52     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat01    image002.jpeg       cat001      Pink        XXL
135     5       118         Title02     Desc02          2020-07-15 16:26:52     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat01    image002.jpeg       cat001      Pink        XXXL
```

Initially I was getting above SQL result where duplicate products were displaying in SQL result due to same product color and different sizes. Then I got help here and I used below query which is working fine now. I am getting below SQL result now where only first product with same pkid and color is displaying in SQL result.

**Current SQL Query I am using**

```
SELECT a.pkid, 
b.subcattitle, 
c.largephotofilename,  
d.title AS cattitle, 
f.title AS colortitle, 
min(n.title) AS sizetitle 
FROM t_store a 
LEFT JOIN t_store_cat d ON a.catpkid=d.catpkid AND d.visible='YES' 
LEFT JOIN t_store_subcat b ON a.subcatpkid=b.subcatpkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_photo c ON a.pkid=c.masterpkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_color e ON a.pkid=e.itempkid 
LEFT JOIN t_store_color f ON e.masterpkid=f.pkid 
LEFT JOIN tr_store_size m ON a.pkid=m.itempkid 
LEFT JOIN t_store_size n ON m.masterpkid=n.pkid 
WHERE a.visible='YES' AND b.visible='YES' AND c.visible='YES' 
AND a.catpkid = 5 
GROUP BY a.pkid, b.subcattitle, c.largephotofilename,  d.title , f.title 
ORDER BY a.createdatetime DESC
```

**SQL Query Result of above query that I wanted**

```
pkid    catpkid subcatpkid  title       description     createdatetime          visible     listprice   ourprice    memberprice     subcattitle largephotofilename  cattitle    colortitle  sizetitle   
132     5       118         Title01     Desc01          2020-07-15 14:44:51     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat01    image001.jpeg       cat001      Gray        L
135     5       118         Title02     Desc02          2020-07-15 16:26:52     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat01    image002.jpeg       cat001      Pink        L
```

But now, when there is a product with different color and same size then again duplicate products are displaying in SQL result like below.

**SQL Query Result With different colors and same size**

```
pkid    catpkid subcatpkid  title       description     createdatetime          visible     listprice   ourprice    memberprice     subcattitle largephotofilename  cattitle    colortitle  sizetitle   
76      3       101         Title76     Desc76          2020-07-15 14:44:51     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat101   image076.jpeg       cat003      Red         FREESIZE
76      3       101         Title76     Desc76          2020-07-15 16:26:52     YES         1599.00     570.00      470.00          SubCat101   image076.jpeg       cat003      Maroon      FREESIZE
```

Now I want to make so only first product with same pkid and size should display in SQL result. Currently they are displaying as 2 different products because they have same pkid and size but different colors.

Still I will need above query where only first product with same pkid and color is displaying in SQL result.

So I want to make so query should work in both cases.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using sub-query like below,

```
SELECT 
    temp.pkid,
    temp.subcattitle,
    temp.largephotofilename,
    temp.cattitle,
    temp.colortitle,
    temp.sizetitle
FROM
    (SELECT 
        a.pkid,
            b.subcattitle,
            c.largephotofilename,
            d.title AS cattitle,
            f.title AS colortitle,
            MIN(n.title) AS sizetitle,
            a.createdatetime
    FROM
        t_store a
    INNER JOIN t_store_cat d ON a.catpkid = d.catpkid
        AND d.visible = 'YES'
    INNER JOIN t_store_subcat b ON a.subcatpkid = b.subcatpkid
    LEFT JOIN tr_store_photo c ON a.pkid = c.masterpkid
    LEFT JOIN tr_store_color e ON a.pkid = e.itempkid
    LEFT JOIN t_store_color f ON e.masterpkid = f.pkid
    LEFT JOIN tr_store_size m ON a.pkid = m.itempkid
    LEFT JOIN t_store_size n ON m.masterpkid = n.pkid
    WHERE
        a.visible = 'YES' AND b.visible = 'YES'
            AND c.visible = 'YES'
            AND a.catpkid = 5
    GROUP BY a.pkid , b.subcattitle , c.largephotofilename , d.title , f.title
    ORDER BY a.createdatetime DESC) AS temp
GROUP BY temp.pkid , temp.subcattitle , temp.largephotofilename , temp.cattitle
HAVING MAX(temp.createdatetime)
ORDER BY temp.createdatetime DESC
```

This query will first filter data based on your criteria and then it will remove duplicate data as you mentioned. To fetch the first row I have added `having clause` and removed `colortitle` from the `group by` of the outer query.

Comment: Thank you very much... it works perfectly as expected.

Comment: Your first 2 joins are both INNER JOINs (just sayin')